# What does "n over 1 without a line between" signify?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm starting to work my way through *Algebra I* by Jacobson after being out of college for 15 years, and he's using an expression I don't remember from college algebra.

It's a number over a number *without* a line between. I assume it means "n divided by 1", is this correct?

[Here's a scan of the expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvI8q.jpg):

[image]

Comment: [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). In general $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ so $\binom{n}1=\frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!}=n$. Another notation is $C(n,k)$. You often find that on calculators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol ${n \choose k}$ is called a binomial coefficient, and it is read as "n choose k". It is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects, unordered, from a collection of $n$ objects. It is equal to $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, where "!" denotes factorial.

Comment: Bonus for the factorial tidbit